# GraphQL & Prisma: why does one redefine types in the application schema when they are already part of the Prisma database schema?

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

Hi — I’ve been following along with a GraphQL/Prisma tutorial (https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/6-authentication/) and I’m wondering why one redefines types in the application schema when they are already part of the Prisma database schema and could be imported from there.

The answer the tutorial gives is “To hide potentially sensitive information from client applications”.  What does this mean exactly?  Why do we replicate definitions in ‘schema.graphql’ and ‘datamodel.prisma’?  Because the definitions are slightly different (i.e. the 'datamodel' contains tags like `@unique`)?   And how are we hiding things from client applications?  I remain perplexed....

Specifically in ‘schema.graphql’ I have

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    links: [Link!]!
}
```

and in 'datamodel.prisma' I have

```
type User {
    id: ID! @unique
    name: String!
    email: String! @unique
    password: String!
    links: [ Link!] !
}
```

Comment: The schema doesn't have the password, that is likely what is meant by "hide potentially sensitive information". This is common practice in any API to not return *all* data from the persistent storage.

Comment: Ah, of course!  It still seems odd to me, having almost the same definition in two separate places, but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema doesn't have the `password` field, that is likely what is meant by "*hide potentially sensitive information*".

This is common practice in any API to not return all data from the persistent storage.

Comment: So basically the models defined in 'schema.graphql' contain only those things that you need to know about, whereas those in 'datamodel.prisma'  contain *everything* that is to be stored?

Comment: Basically yes. In this case, you would never show the password field. I would hope it's hashed anyway so the only thing you should do is pass another hashed password in, along with a username or email and confirm a match.